# How to select lines from a text file and then randomize the order of those lines? (in python)

Tags: python, random

The problem I have is that I want to select a number of lines within a range from a text file, and then randomize the order of those lines. I know that this is how to randomize the text file, but how do I target a certain number of lines to randomize?

````
with open("infile.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
random.shuffle(lines)
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)```
````

Comment: It's just a list.  To shuffle lines 10 to 20, do `lines = lines[:10] + random.shuffle(lines[10:20]) + lines[20:]`.

Comment: @Tim Doesn't work, and if it did, it would be needlessly complicated.

Comment: @TimRoberts It doesn't work, it gives the error "can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list"

Comment: Unclear what you mean with select.

Comment: @KellyBundy for example, I only want to randomize lines 1-5 of a text file. So I want to target or select those lines and randomize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that is the best solution, but it works

```
n_start=1
n_end=4
with open("infile.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
tmp=lines[n_start:n_end]
random.shuffle(tmp)
lines[n_start:n_end]=tmp
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```